# How to call a GPU task periodically using Hybridizer

Tags: c#, hybridizer

I'm trying to use hybridizer for computations using a GPU in C#. I tried to embed my GPU code in a .NET library use Altimesh Hybridizer. Let's call it GPU_DLL.

This library has to be used in another project, let's call it Test_GPU_Caller. The GPU code is called periodically using a timer as shown in the following code :

```
class Program
{

    static GPU_DLL.GPU_DLL gpuDllTest = new GPU_DLL.GPU_DLL();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer tmr = new Timer(100);
        tmr.Elapsed += Tmr_Elapsed;
        tmr.Start();

        while (true) ;
    }
    private static void Tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        gpuDllTest.Test("GPU_DLL_CUDA.dll");
    }

}
```

Test function is implemented in a .NET library with the following code :

```
public class GPU_DLL
{
    [EntryPoint("run")]
    public void Run(int N, double[] a, double[] b)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, N, i => { a[i] += b[i]; });
    }

    public void Test(string dllName)
    {
        // 268 MB allocated on device -- should fit in every CUDA compatible GPU
        int N = 1024 * 1024 * 16;
        double[] acuda = new double[N];
        double[] adotnet = new double[N];

        double[] b = new double[N];

        Random rand = new Random();

        //Initialize acuda et adotnet and b by some doubles randoms, acuda and adotnet have same numbers. 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            acuda[i] = rand.NextDouble();
            adotnet[i] = acuda[i];
            b[i] = rand.NextDouble();
        }

        cudaDeviceProp prop;
        cuda.GetDeviceProperties(out prop, 0);
        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda(dllName).SetDistrib(prop.multiProcessorCount * 16, 128);

        // create a wrapper object to call GPU methods instead of C#
        dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(this);

        // run the method on GPU
        wrapped.Run(N, acuda, b);

        // run .Net method
        Run(N, adotnet, b);

        // verify the results
        for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
        {
            if (acuda[k] != adotnet[k])
                Console.Out.WriteLine("ERROR !");
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("DONE");
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

GPU_DLL has been Hybridized first, and compiled. When i launch the program, i get an error : 
System.ArgumentException : 'Un élément avec la même clé a déjà été ajouté.' (in french...)

Does someone know how to use GPU code called periodically using Hybridizer ? A sample project is welcome ;)

Best regards,
Valentin

Comment: The error in french relates to your locale. (it is an uncaught system exception).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing seems to relate to timer calling the function a second time before first call has finished. According to documentation, your timer setup will call the timer function callback every 100 milliseconds, however it will not wait for previous run to be done (running it on my system requires 1.3 seconds for first iteration, and ~650ms on subsequent calls).

HybRunner is not thread-safe. Also, note that the CUDA context is attached to a thread, and using another thread requires another CUDA context.

Here is a alternate implementation to address your issue using a worker thread that executes GPU-related tasks:

First, declare synchronization components:

```
    static bool workerrunning = false;
    static object started = new object();

    static Queue<object> tasks = new Queue<object>();
    static object watch = new object();
```

The worker thread loop could be the following:

```
    public static void HybridLoop(object p)
    {
        lock (started)
        {
            workerrunning = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(started);
        }
        while (workerrunning)
        {
            object currenttask = null;
            // get next task
            lock (watch)
            {
                if (tasks.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(watch);
                }
                if (tasks.Count != 0)
                {
                    currenttask = tasks.Dequeue();
                    // NOTE: here, we illustrate more tasks than doable => clear
                    tasks.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (currenttask != null)
            {
                gpuDllTest.Test("GPU_DLL_CUDA.dll");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, we clear the task queue as it is populated faster than consumed.

The code to start the worker thread:

```
        System.Threading.Thread hybridrunner = new System.Threading.Thread(HybridLoop);
        lock(started)
        {
            hybridrunner.Start();
            Monitor.Wait(started);
        }
```

Once worker is started, timer can be started:

```
        System.Timers.Timer tmr = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
        tmr.Elapsed += Tmr_Elapsed;
        tmr.Start();

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Runner started - press return to stop");
        var key = Console.Read();
```

Your timer elapse function is simply a task enqueing:

```
    private static void Tmr_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (watch)
        {
            tasks.Enqueue(1);
            Monitor.Pulse(watch);
        }
    }
```

Once done, runner can be stopped to avoid tail-running thread:

```
        workerrunning = false;
        lock (watch)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
            tasks.Enqueue(0);
            Monitor.Pulse(watch);
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Runner stopping");

        hybridrunner.Join();

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Runner stopped");
```

Example execution log:

```
DONE
Execution took 1026 milliseconds
DONE
Execution took 642 milliseconds
DONE
Execution took 614 milliseconds
Runner started - press return to stop
DONE
DONE
DONE

Runner stopping
DONE
Runner stopped
```

As a final note, you may want to do some initialization such as HybRunner.Cuda(), only once, and then perform other tasks in the same worker thread.